# JAXB Generating Classes Issue

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, cxf

I am trying to use Eclipse to generate a few Java Classes. But somehow I am running into issues. When I try to do it, I get this error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.xml.apis.schemas.MPLSVPNListItem" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 9 of file:/C:/Workspace/MyFiles/WebContent/WEB-INF/XSDFiles/jaxb_binding.xml

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "MPLSVPNListItem" is generated from here.
  line 3122 of file:/C:/Workspace/MyFiles/WebContent/WEB-INF/XSDFiles/APIcTypes.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 9 of file:/C:/Workspace/MyFiles/WebContent/WEB-INF/XSDFiles/jaxb_binding.xml

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 3122 of file:/C:/Workspace/MyFiles/WebContent/WEB-INF/XSDFiles/APIcTypes.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

I am using the JAXB Binding file (jaxb_binding.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="APIcTypes.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='MPLS-VPNListItem']">
            <jxb:class name="MPLS_VPNListItem" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="APIcTypes.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xs:complexType[@name='MPLSVPNListItem']">
            <jxb:class name="MPLSVPNListItem" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Because I think these two tags are causing the problem.

I have to say that APIcTypes.xsd is actually an import in the XSD that I am trying to generate the classes for.

The includes structure is like:
API.xsd --> APIRequests.xsd --> APIcTypes.xsd --> APIsTypes.xsd.

I hope this is understandable. If you need any more info, please do let me know. Just cant get it to work!

Comment: Your final `<jxb:bindings>` element shouldn’t be needed, since `MPLSVPNListItem` should be the default generated class name.  Try removing that binding.

Comment: What is the problem? Do the bindings not work?

Comment: Sorry, Just forgot to reply back, dropping the second binding worked.